Help defining all pathways of a sample from the same start-point
This is slightly different from this question. We are focusing on finding all pathways of a sample rather than partitions of equal area:
Suppose we have the following sample:
$$\small{\mathcal{S}=\left\{(-1.5,-1.7),(1.5,-1.2),(-1.5,-.7),(-1.5,-.2),(-1.5,.3),(-1.5,.8),(-1.5,1.3),(-1.5,1.8)\right\}}$$
Consider the following steps:

Take a point $x_0$ from $\mathcal{S}$
Take a point from $\mathcal{S}$ (excluding $x_0$) with smallest euclidean distance from point $x_0\in\mathcal{S}$, where point is denoted $x_1$. (If more than one point has the smallest Euclidean distance from $x_0$, take either point).
Take a point in $\mathcal{S}$ (excluding $x_0$ and $x_1$) with smallest euclidean distance from $x_1$, where point is denoted $x_2$.
Take a point in $\mathcal{S}$ (excluding $x_0$, $x_1$, and $x_2$) with smallest euclidean distance from $x_2$, where point is denoted $x_3$.
Repeat the process excluding points $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,$ etc. until all points in the sample are "denoted". (This should occur eight times.)

Question: If more than one sample point has the same Euclidean distance from $x_0$, $x_1$, $x_2$, etc. How do we take all possible pathways?
For example, in the sample $$\small{\mathcal{S}=\left\{(-1.5,-1.7),(1.5,-1.2),(-1.5,-.7),(-1.5,-.2),(-1.5,.3),(-1.5,.8),(-1.5,1.3),(-1.5,1.8)\right\}}$$ when $x_0=(-1.5,-.2)$ then since $(-1.5,-.7)$ and $(-1.5,.3)$ have the smallest Euclidean distance from $(-1.5,-.2)$, and for point $x_1=(-1.5,-.7)$, since $(-1.5,-1.7)$ and $(-1.5,.3)$ have the smallest Euclidean distance from $(-1.5,-.7)$, we take three pathways:
$$\small{(-1.5,-.2)\to(-1.5,-.7)\to(-1.5,-1.7)\to(-1.5,.3)\to(-1.5,.8)\to(-1.5,1.3)\to(-1.5,1.8)\to(1.5,-1.2)}$$
$$\small{(-1.5,-.2)\to(-1.5,-.7)\to(-1.5,.3)\to(-1.5,.8)\to(-1.5,1.3)\to(-1.5,1.8)\to(-1.5,-1.7)\to(1.5,-1.2)}$$
$$\small{(-1.5,-.2)\to(-1.5,.3)\to(-1.5,.8)\to(-1.5,1.3)\to(-1.5,1.8)\to(-1.5,-.7)\to(-1.5,-1.7)\to(1.5,-1.2)}$$
I don't know how to solve this with code, but here is my attempt:

There is only one $x_0$
A sample of eight points has at most seven $x_1$ with the same distance from $x_0$
A sample of eight points has at most six $x_2$ with the same distance from $x_1$
A sample of eight points has at most five $x_3$ with the same distance from $x_2$
$$\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\vdots$$
A sample of eight points has at most one $x_7$ with the same distance from $x_6$

We take all possible $8$-tuples of $\left\{x_0,x_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_7\right\}$
 T = Tuples[{{1}, Range[7], Range[6], Range[5], Range[4], Range[3], 
   Range[2], Range[1]}]

I have difficulty explaining the rest but that is irrelevant. The code is bad.
S1[x_, y_, z_] := 
 S1[x, y, z] = 
  Piecewise[{{z, T[[x, y]] > z}, {T[[x, y]], T[[x, y]] <= z}}]
S = {{-1.5, -1.7}, {1.5, -1.2}, {-1.5, -.7}, {-1.5, -.2}, {-1.5, .3}, \
{-1.5, .8}, {-1.5, 1.3}, {-1.5, 
   1.8}}; (* Random list of points in the sample *)
DeleteDuplicates[Table[{
   X[1] = S[[2]];  (* x0=X1, the fourth point of the sample S *)
   Y[1] = DeleteCases[S, X[1]]; (* Deletes X1=x0 from sample S *)
   X[x_, y] := 
    Nearest[Y[x - 1, y], 
      X[x - 1, y]][[S1[y, x, 
       Length[Nearest[Y[x - 1, y], X[x - 1, y]]]]]]; (* Takes X2=x1, 
   X3=x2, X4=x3,... *)
   Y[x_, y] := DeleteCases[Y[x - 1, y], X[x, y]]; (* Deletes X1=
   x0 from the sample S *)
   P[y] := Table[X[x, y], {x, 1, Length[S]}] (* 
   Lists all points in pathway X *),
   ListofAllr[y_] := 
    Table[EuclideanDistance[P[y][[x]], P[y][[x + 1]]], {x, 1, 
      Length[P[y]] - 1}]; (* 
   Lists the Euclidean distance between all consecutive points in \
Pathway X *)
   IndexofNonOutliers[y] = 
    Flatten[Position[ListofAllr[y], 
       Alternatives @@ DeleteAnomalies[ListofAllr[y]]]](* 
     Index of i where Euclidean[P[i],P[i+1]] is a non-
     outlier in 'ListofAllDistances' *)
     D1[y] = Table[P[y][[x]], Evaluate[{x, IndexofNonOutliers[y]}]](* 
   Excludes integer i where r_i are outliers *),
   DistanceD1[y] = 
    Table[EuclideanDistance[P[y][[x]], P[y][[x + 1]]], 
     Evaluate[{x, IndexofNonOutliers[y]}]] ;(* {x,IndexofNon-
   Outliers} removes the distance line segments with index i such \
that r_i is an outlier *)
   arrow[coord_, e_] := 
    Piecewise[{{Style[Arrow[coord], Red, Thickness[.01], 
        Arrowheads[0.06]], 
       Boole[MemberQ[N /@ D1[y], First@coord]] == 0}, {Style[
        Arrow[coord], Black, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[0.06]], 
       Boole[MemberQ[N /@ D1[y], First@coord]] == 1}}];
   String1[y] = ToString /@ P[y],
   (*Labels arrows for "pathway" P*)
   Edge[y] = 
    PathGraph[Range[Length[P[y]]], VertexCoordinates -> P[y], 
     EdgeShapeFunction -> arrow, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotRangePadding -> .2],
   PD1[y] = DistanceD1[y]/Total[DistanceD1[y]],
   -Total[PD1 [y] Log[2, PD1[y]]]}, {y, 1, Length[S]}]]

Question: Is there a simpler code which gives what I want mid-post (i.e., original question)?

Can $x_1$ be the same as $x_0$?

@A.Kato  No, $x_1$ has to be different.

Fast answer provided here 306519 as part of the visualisation question.

Recursive function call will help you.
(I understand that $x_0, x_1,..., x_7$ are all distinct, and a permutation of all the points in $S$.)
Clear["Global`*"]

S={{−1.5,−1.7},{1.5,−1.2},{−1.5,−.7},{−1.5,−.2},{−1.5,.3},{−1.5,.8},{−1.5,1.3},{−1.5,1.8}}};

I prefer working on exact numbers, so put
S = Rationalize /@ S


ClearAll[pathways, findnext];

pathways[start_List] := findnext[{start}];

findnext[path_List] := Module[{candidates, now},
   If[ContainsAll[path, S], Return[{path}]];
   now = Last[path];
   candidates = 
    MinimalBy[Complement[S, path], EuclideanDistance[now, #] &];
   Join @@ Table[findnext[Append[path, next]], {next, candidates}]
];

The function findnext[ ] calls itself recursively. findnext[{x_0,...,x_k}] will return a list of all possible paths, each of which is of the form {x_0,...,x_k,x_(k+1)}.
Let us try:
init = S[[4]]


ans = pathways[init];
Grid[Prepend[ans, Subscript[x, #] & /@ Range[0, Length[S] - 1]], Dividers -> All]


Or, as a list of position indices in $S$:
 ans /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> Position[S, {x, y}][[1, 1]]

(* {{4,3,1,5,6,7,8,2},{4,3,5,6,7,8,1,2},{4,5,6,7,8,3,1,2}} *)


When $x_0=(1.5,-1.2)$, I get $x_1=(-1.5,1.8)$ instead of $x_1=(-1.5,-1.7)$. (Notice, $(-1.5,-1.7)$ has a smaller Euclidean distance from $x_0=(1.5,-1.2)$.) How do we fix this?

Also, see this question.
